# Запятая в обороте с "будто" нужна или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

*Ему казалось, будто он совершил непоправимую ошибку(,) и теперь враг сам себе.*

Answer (score 3):

Не нужна. Вторая часть после И тоже относится к **будто** (будто он совершил ошибку и будто сам себе враг). Хоть то, что он враг, и следствие из мнимой ошибки, всё равно то, что он враг себе, ему **казалось**, это общий член.